# it's strange that he * it's strange for him to

Tags: syntactic-analysis, subjunctive-mood

My wife and I are waiting for a friend. It's late. I say to my wife:

- *It's strange that he should be late. He's always on time.*
- *It's strange for him to be late. He's always on time.*
- *It's strange that he is late. He's always on time.*

Would the three of them sound natural?

Comment: Yes, they all sound fine, at least to me (AmE). I'm told AmE uses the subjunctive more that BrE.

Comment: @medica But there ain't no subjunctives in  those there examples ....

Comment: @Araucaria - I thought the first example might be, but thanks for pointing that out. Glad you're back, btw!